# is there a reason why the some inputs are not added to respectives list?

Tags: python, list, printing, prompt

i´m practicing with python and making a code that add bonus in lists by respective price, i got that price < 100 be added in respective list, but not the same with middle_bonus and advanced_bonus whom are printed empty, some help please? here the code...

```
basic_bonus = []
middle_bonus = []
advanced_bonus = []
prompt = "\nPlease enter bonus price: "
prompt += "\n(Enter 'N' when finished.) "
while True:
    bonus = eval(input(prompt))
    continua = str(input("\nDo you want enter other bonus[y/n]: ? "))
    if continua == 'y' and bonus < 100:
        basic_bonus.append(bonus)
    if continua == 'y' and bonus >= 100 and bonus == 200:
        middle_bonus.append(bonus)
    if continua == 'y' and bonus > 200 and bonus == 300:
        advanced_bonus.append(bonus)
    if continua == 'y' and bonus > 300:
        print("Sorry, not available, try again")
    if continua == 'n':
        print("Total basic bonus: ", str(basic_bonus))
        print("Total middle bonus: ", str(middle_bonus))
        print("Total advanced bonus: ", str(advanced_bonus))
        break
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`. You are expecting an `int`, so call `int` on the return value of `input`.

Comment: You are using `and` where you should be using `or`. For example, if you enter 150, that's not 200, so you won't append to `middle_bonus`.

Comment: As a reason among other similar ones, `bonus >= 100 and bonus == 200` solely means `bonus == 200`. `==` means "equals", not "smaller than". You should also use `elif` and `else`.

Comment: When the user types 'n', all if statements get skipped, except the last one, and also the list is not appended as the if statement is skipped.

Comment: Thank ypu for the comments and all of the options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your `if`s testing the wrong values. Better like this:

```py
basic_bonus = []
middle_bonus = []
advanced_bonus = []
prompt = "\nPlease enter bonus price: "
prompt += "\n(Enter 'N' when finished.) "
while True:
    bonus = int(input(prompt))
    continua = input("\nDo you want enter other bonus[y/n]: ? ").lower()
    if continua == 'y' and bonus < 100:
        basic_bonus.append(bonus)
    elif continua == 'y' and bonus <= 200:
        middle_bonus.append(bonus)
    elif continua == 'y' and bonus <= 300:
        advanced_bonus.append(bonus)
    elif continua == 'y' and bonus > 300:
        print("Sorry, not available, try again")
    elif continua == 'n':
        print("Total basic bonus: ", basic_bonus)
        print("Total middle bonus: ", middle_bonus)
        print("Total advanced bonus: ", advanced_bonus)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was so helpfull for this case..